# How to disable Home button android 4.4?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-homebutton

I write lock screen for Android 4.4. I can't block home button. I start new Activity in onPause function ( or start in service) but If onPause is called by Home button, Activity start delayed 5s. How to fix it? (In google play HiLocker fixed start new Activity with home button no delay.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not supposed to tinker with the home button